# OOP PHP SQL select

Tags: php, sql, oop

I create class Database:

```
class Database  
{  

    private $db_host = "localhost";   
    private $db_user = "root";   
    private $db_pass = "";   
    private $db_name = "test";

    private $con = false;
    private $result = array();

}
```

There are more functions but is not important to mention them.

I have this function:

```
public function sql($sql){
    $query = @mysql_query($sql);
    if($query){
        // If the query returns >= 1 assign the number of rows to numResults
        $this->numResults = mysql_num_rows($query);
        // Loop through the query results by the number of rows returned
        for($i = 0; $i < $this->numResults; $i++){
            $r = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            $key = array_keys($r);
            for($x = 0; $x < count($key); $x++){
                // Sanitizes keys so only alphavalues are allowed
                if(!is_int($key[$x])){
                    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 1){
                        $this->result[$i][$key[$x]] = $r[$key[$x]];
                    }else if(mysql_num_rows($query) < 1){
                        $this->result = null;
                    }else{
                        $this->result[$key[$x]] = $r[$key[$x]];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true; // Query was successful
    }else{
        array_push($this->result,mysql_error());
        return false; // No rows where returned
    }
}
```

The problem is when i use in my main script for example a simple select is working fine:

```
$db = new Database();
$db->connect();
$db->sql("Select * FROM crudclass");
$res = $db->getResult();

print_r($res);
echo "<br>";
foreach($res as $output){
echo $output["id"]."&nbsp;";
    echo $output["name"]."&nbsp;";
echo $output["email"]."<br />";
}
?>
```

I get all the results:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Name 1 [email] => name1@email.com ) [1] =>                                                                     Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Name 2 [email] => name2@email.com ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3   [name] => Name 3 [email] => name3@email.com ) ) 
1 Name 1 name1@email.com
2 Name 2 name2@email.com
3 Name 3 name3@email.com
```

but if i want to use for example WHERe like this:

```
$db->sql("Select * FROM crudclass where id=1");
```

i get this error

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Name 1 [email] => name1@email.com ) 

Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 14
1 
Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 15
1 
Warning: Illegal string offset 'email' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 16
1

Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 14
N 
Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 15
N 
Warning: Illegal string offset 'email' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 16
N

Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 14
n 
Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 15
n 
Warning: Illegal string offset 'email' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 16
n
```

Comment: what is in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 18 (put with context)

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_*`. for new code. As mentioned in the documentation (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php -- big red warning!), it is deprecated and should be considered unfit for future use. Use `mysqli_*` or, better yet, PDO instead. Further, please stop using the `@` error suppressor -- you're only creating problems for yourself.

Comment: Why not just use the MySQLi extension? It's already OO and fairly bulletproof.

Comment: @Ethan It isn't uncommon to build a wrapper for database access, saves writing all the connector code and what not, gives you a container class to inject so you keep control of your concurrent connections, too. That said.... yeah. Copy pasta mysqli code beats some roll-your-own wrapper built with 1994's hot new technology.

Comment: as kAlmAcetA asked, which is line 18 of index.php?

Comment: the index is something like that:

    <?php

include("DataBase_Class.php");


    $db = new Database();
    $db->connect();
    $db->sql("Select * FROM crudclass where `id`=1");
    $res = $db->getResult();

print_r($res);
echo "<br>";
    foreach($res as $output){
 echo $output["id"]."&nbsp;";
        echo $output["name"]."&nbsp;";
 echo $output["email"]."<br />";
    }
    ?>

Comment: And the error i get is :

Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Name 1 [email] => name1@email.com ) 

Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 14
1 
Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 15
1 
Warning: Illegal string offset 'email' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 16
1

Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 14
N 
Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 15
N 
Warning: Illegal string offset 'email' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 16
N

Comment: Try `var_dump($output);` in your foreach and post what's there. It sounds like it's not populating with what you think it should.

Comment: string(1) "1"
string(6) "Name 1" 
string(15) "name1@email.com"

Comment: There's your problem. `$res = $db->getResult();` is returning only one row. So when you iterate through $res in the foreach, it's just going through that row, not multiple rows.

Comment: When i use the function without WHERE is all ok. I get all the rows. The problem is when i use WHERE...See my update code

Comment: It's breaking down where you build your results array in the sql function, which is needlessly complicated. If you convert the code from mysql to PDO or mysqli, you should be able to get the arrays out better.

Comment: There isn't a way to fix it without using PDO?

Comment: @Chris Agreed. I just think that based on the code he provided, he isn't trying to do some grand optimization. It looks like he just wasn't aware of MySQLi and was trying to reinvent some of it.

Comment: There is, by going through that code to figure out what's breaking it. But since the mysql_* functions are going away in the very near future, it's best to go ahead and use the new functions instead of rewriting it again.

Comment: @MegasAlexandros Are you trying to write broken code on purpose? Why are you willing to try ANYTHING BUT PDO?! It makes no sense -- I sincerely hope no one is paying for whatever it is you're coding.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
Select * FROM crudclass where `id`=1
```

Comment: Putting the column name in back ticks isn't even an answer, in my opinion. The query, which is simply passed to the database, has no possible effect on PHP runtime errors. This answer doesn't address the question at all. -1